# EF not saving Unicode characters

Tags: entity-framework, encoding, unicode

I have a table with an `NVARCHAR` column. When I save data which contains Unicode characters to this column, EF is sending the data as `VARCHAR` which manes my Unicode characters are replaced.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (Id INT IDENTITY, Name NVARCHAR(MAX));
```

I try to set `MyTable.Name` to "100 ≠ 200" and here's what I find in SQL Profiler:

> exec sp_executesql N'update [MyTable] set [Name] = @0 where (([Id] = @1))
>   ',N'@0 varchar(max) ,@1 int',@0='100 ? 200',@1=1

Notice the data type of `@0` is `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead of `NVARCHAR(MAX)`. How do I fix this?

**Update**
Notice that the proper Unicode character is coming through in the request. This code is pulling the character our of the model:

[image: Unicode character correct in request.]

Comment: What are the values of `responseEncoding` and `requestEncoding` attributes in Web.config `<globalization>` tag?

Comment: @FabioS - I don't have a `globalization` element at all, my page's encoding is set to UTF-8. But the correct Unicode character is definitely coming through in the request, check the screen shot I'm about to add...

Comment: Maybe this link can help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.entityfunctions.asunicode%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: I can see the Unicode character being set on the EF object. The part that is screwing it up is when EF generates the SQL to perform the update.

Comment: Did you check the collation? Because with my situation I could not get back the Turkish char 'Ş'. After correcting the collation I got the expected results.

Comment: fascinating, could you specify what EF approach did you used? is it code first, model first, or database first? If you are the later two, it seems the `edmx` is going stupid. please check the file using plain text editor. some can be solved by directly editing the `edmx` file.